# problema con un programa de documentos de texto

Tags: c++

Este programa consiste en un pseudo intento de bloc de notas que crea documentos, escribe en ellos, los lee y te permite seguir escribiendo en ellos así como te permite eliminarlos pero no termina de funcionar, el problema reside en el case 3 del switch he comprobado el resto de cases del switch y funcionan perfectamente pero al continuar el documento, en el case 3, para añadir nuevo texto a un documento me borra todo el texto dejando un documento completamente en blanco.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string salir="salir",nombre,escrito;;
    for(int o=1;o!=0;o)
    {
    cout<<"Seleccione una opcion:\n1:Escribir una nota nueva\n2:Leer una nota\n3:Continuar una nota anterior\n4:Borrar una nota\n0:Salir\n";
    cin>>o;
    system("cls");
    switch(o)
    {
        case 1:{cout<<"Introduzca el nombre que tendra el archivo: ";
                cin.ignore();
                getline(cin,nombre);
                ofstream archivo1(nombre.c_str());
                cout<<"Escriba lo que quiere que contenga el archivo: ";
                do{
                    getline(cin,escrito);
                    if(escrito!=salir)
                    {
                        archivo1<<escrito<<endl;
                    }
                }while(escrito!=salir);
                archivo1.close();
                cout<<"Archivo creado"<<endl;
               }
            break;
        case 2:{cout<<"Introduzca el nombre del archivo que quieres abrir: "<<endl;
                cin.ignore();
                getline(cin,nombre);
                system("cls");
                ifstream archivo2(nombre.c_str());
                if(archivo2.fail()){cout<<"El archivo seleccionado no es valido"<<endl;}else{
                string linea;
                while(!archivo2.eof())
                {
                    getline(archivo2,linea);
                    if(!archivo2.eof())
                    cout<<linea<<endl;
                }
                archivo2.close();
                }
                system("pause");
                }
            break;
        case 3:{cout<<"Introduzca el nombre del archivo que quiera continuar: ";
                cin.ignore();
                getline(cin,nombre);
                ifstream archivo3(nombre.c_str());
                if(archivo3.fail()){cout<<"El archivo seleccionado no es valido"<<endl;}else{
                string linea;
                while(!archivo3.eof())
                {
                    getline(archivo3,linea);
                    if(!archivo3.eof())
                    cout<<linea<<endl;
                }
                archivo3.close();
                }
                ofstream archivo4(nombre.c_str());
                if(archivo4.fail()){o=5;}else{
                archivo4.open(nombre.c_str(),ios::app);
                do{
                    getline(cin,escrito);
                    archivo4<<escrito<<endl;
                }while(escrito!=salir);
                archivo4.close();
                cout<<"Archivo guardado"<<endl;
                }
               }
            break;
        case 4:{cout<<"Introduzca el nombre del archivo que quiera borrar: ";
                cin.ignore();
                getline(cin,nombre);
                remove(nombre.c_str());
               }
            break;
        case 0:{cout<<"Saliendo del programa"<<endl;
                system("pause");
               }
            break;
        default:{cout<<"Opcion seleccionada no valida";
                system("pause");
                }
            break;
    }
    system("cls");
    }
    cout<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Cuando abres un flujo de archivo de salida, por defecto se descarta el contenido previo del archivo. Si quieres escribir al final del archivo debes indicarlo:

```
if (std::ofstream archivo("nombre.txt", std::ios::binary::app))
{
    std::cout << "Archivo abierto\n";
}
else
{
    std::cout << "Fallo al abrir el archivo\n";
}
```

El modo de apertura [`std::ios::binary::app`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/openmode) permite anexar (*`app`end*) datos al final del archivo abierto.